# Insertar información de un Stored Procedure a una tabla temporal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Tengo un Stored Procedure del cual obtengo información y necesito insertar esa información en una tabla temporal, esto es lo que tengo:

```
EXEC AR_2019 'ANUAL', 2019, 03  
INTO #AR_FAMILIAS_2019
```

Tengo el error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es que efectivamente es una sintaxis no permitida. Para lo que intentas, puedes usar una clausula del tipo:

```
INSERT INTO <TABLA> (<COLUMNAS>)
EXEC <SP>
```

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #Procesos (
    SPID        INT,
    Status      VARCHAR(255),
    Login       VARCHAR(255),
    HostName    VARCHAR(255),
    BlkBy       VARCHAR(255),
    DBName      VARCHAR(255),
    Command     VARCHAR(255),
    CPUTime     INT,
    DiskIO      INT,
    LastBatch   VARCHAR(255),
    ProgramName VARCHAR(255),
    SPID2       INT,
    REQUESTID   INT
)

INSERT INTO #Procesos (SPID, Status, Login, HostName, BlkBy, DBName, Command, CPUTime, DiskIO, LastBatch, ProgramName, SPID2, REQUESTID)
EXEC SP_WHO2

SELECT  *
    FROM #Procesos

DROP TABLE #Procesos
```

Importante:

- La tabla tiene que tener al menos la misma cantidad de columnas que los que retorna el Sp
- Los tipos de datos tiene que ser consistentes con los del SP.
- El orden de inserción de las columnas tiene que ser idéntico al orden de las columnas del SP.